# WPF rendering control to Bitmap without Window

Tags: c#, wpf

So we have a WPF application that shows some charts created using the Live Charts library. However I got the task to render the charts in the background, and save them to a PNG image without displaying a WPF window. I found an article online that takes a UserControl and does exactly that, but trying it myself I only get a transparent image of 80 by 50 pixels.

Unfortunately I am not very familiar with the WPF internals of rendering, so any help is really appreciated. This is my code rendered down to the bare minimum with the simplest chart example from LiveChart itself.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using LiveCharts.Geared;
using LiveCharts;

namespace Screenshot2Pdf {
    class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var Series = new SeriesCollection();
            var r = new Random();

            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) // 30 series
            {
                var trend = 0d;
                var values = new double[10000];

                for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++) // 10k points each
                {
                    trend += (r.NextDouble() < .8 ? 1 : -1) * r.Next(0, 10);
                    values[j] = trend;
                }

                var series = new LineSeries {
                    Values = values.AsGearedValues().WithQuality(Quality.Low),
                    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                    StrokeThickness = .5,
                    PointGeometry = null //use a null geometry when you have many series
                };

                Series.Add(series);
            }

            var chart = new CartesianChart();

            chart.Series = Series;

            chart.BeginInit();
            chart.EndInit();

            // Measure and arrange the tile
            chart.Measure(new System.Windows.Size {
                Height = double.PositiveInfinity,
                Width = double.PositiveInfinity
            });
            chart.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0,
               chart.DesiredSize.Width,
               chart.DesiredSize.Height));

            chart.UpdateLayout();

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)chart.DesiredSize.Width, (int)chart.DesiredSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(chart);

            PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            png.Save(stream);
            var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

            image.Save(@"D:\bitmap.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exact same code, but rendered in a WPF window gives a much larger image (also clearly not stretched) and not transparent, but with a white background.

Comment: Putting the breakpoint on chart.Arrange shows that the desiredsize is also 80*50.

Comment: That just generates a transparent image. Just larger.

Comment: Just using the most basic example from LiveCharts. https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/30%20Series%2010k%20pts%20each

Comment: I don't know LiveCharts, but since you set `Fill = Brushes.Transparent` on a LineSeries, you should probably also set `Stroke` to something non-null and non-transparent. There may be property values that are set by default Styles in a Window application, but aren't set in yours.

Comment: I just tried rendering a simple Grid with height and width explicitly set to 500 and Background colour to Brushes.Beige. Gives the same result: transparent image...

Comment: Creating a Grid with a Background, calling Measure, Arrange, UpdateLayout, then Render it into a RenderTargetBitmap works fine for me.

Comment: Yea, my mistake sorry. So it's definetely an issue in the making of the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké I am not sure why. As said before I am not very familiar with WPF's internal rendering mechanism and what triggers it, but the solution is to wrap the Chart in a Viewbox. The following code does the trick:

```
        var viewbox = new Viewbox();
        viewbox.Child = chart;
        viewbox.Measure(chart.RenderSize);
        viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), chart.RenderSize));
        chart.Update(true, true); //force chart redraw
        viewbox.UpdateLayout();

        // RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)chart.DesiredSize.Width, (int)chart.DesiredSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(500, 500, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(chart);

        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\bitmap.png")) {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
```